# How to enlarge uitableview cell image on touch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the following code to detect a touch on a table cell image. How would I go about enlarging the image on that touch?

The part I'm stuck on is how would I make the cell.userSubmittedImageView accessible from the myFunction method?

from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
...
    cell.userSubmittedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.userSubmittedImageView.tag = indexPath.row;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.userSubmittedImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

    return cell;  
}
-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);  
}
```

Comment: Why are you stuck? You have gesture.view, that will be the image view you tapped, and you have gesture.view.tag, which will give you the indexPath.row of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your *userSubmittedImageView* is an *UIImageView* you can do

`UIImageView * userSubmittedImageView = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;`